# Capybara not detecting class after a click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have an spec as follows. It will work ok If I manually do the testing, but If I run the spec I get the following error below.

```
    before(:each) do 
      @user_having_unread_message = FactoryGirl.create(:user_having_unread_message)
      login_as(@user_having_unread_message, scope: :user)
      visit conversations_path
      within("section.items-group") do
        first(:link, "Test message").click
      end
    end

    it "list all messages", touch: true do 
      within(".messages-group") do
        page.should have_content "Test message"
      end
    end
```

This is the error I get

```
  1) Messages GET /:username/messages when signed in and active list all messages
     Failure/Error: within(".messages-group") do
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css ".messages-group"
     # ./spec/features/messages_spec.rb:84:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the `ElementNotFound` for `.messages-group` since If I click manually on the "Test message" link I can see it on the next page.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you try: `page.all(:css, '.messages-group')`

Comment: I get other different error: `Failure/Error: page.all(:css, '.messages-group').should have_content "Test message"
       expected there to be text "Test message" in "#"`

Answer (score 0):

> > page.should have_css('.messages-group', :text => 'Textmessage')

It'll help you.